# buinding and running in different gcc

Tags: c++, gcc, build

- environment A: centos7(same os) / gcc.7.3.1(higher gcc)
- environment B: centos7(same os) / gcc.4.8.5(lower gcc)

I have built an C++ executable in environment A and run it in environment B.
I haven't had a problem so far, but could there be a problem with this approach?

Comment: Please tell more about your software, and provide some [mre] in your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, building a static executable improves portability.

So compile your C++ files with `g++ -O -Wall -Wextra -g` and link the object files with `g++ -static *.o`

Alternatively, use dynamically only `libc.so`, not the C++ standard library. So link with `g++ *.o -Bstatic` *your libraries* `-Bdynamic -lc`

For details, read the documentation of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), of [GNU binutils](https://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/), perhaps of [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/), and the [Program Library Howto](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/) and Drepper's paper [*How to write shared libraries*](https://www.ukuug.org/events/linux2002/papers/pdf/dsohowto.pdf)

Notice that to run an executable (see [elf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/elf.5.html) and [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and other [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)....) you don't need a compiler.

You may want to use [strace(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) and [ldd(1)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ldd.1.html) on machine B.

Don't forget to have many testcases.

Notice that GCC, Bash, Binutils, are [free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html). You are allowed to download and study their source code and improve it (there are licensing conditions when you redistribute an improved binary, read their [GPL license](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/quick-guide-gplv3.en.html))

You could have legal or licensing issues (e.g. if your C++ code uses [Qt](https://qt.io/)). You may need to consult a lawyer about them.

See also [LinuxFromScratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/).